# C++ -- OpenProcess returns error code 87

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this problem with OpenProcess function for the win32 api. Program is intended to read an integer from a program given the program PID and address of integer through userinput.

```
int main() {

 DWORD pidz;

 int buffer[1];

 int temp;

 int* ptr_i;

 std::cout << "Type the address of i in programA: ";
 std::cin >> std::hex >> temp;
 std::cout << "\n";
 ptr_i = (int*)temp;

 std::cout << "Enter PID of programA: ";
 std::cin >> pidz;
 std::cout << "\n\n";

 HANDLE handle_prgmA = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,0,pidz);
 if (handle_prgmA==NULL) {
  std::cout << "***Could not assign handle\n";
  HRESULT apa = GetLastError();
  std::cout << apa << "\n";
 }

 if (ReadProcessMemory(handle_prgmA,ptr_i,&buffer,4,NULL)) {
  std::cout << buffer[0];
 }
 else {
  std::cout << "***Could not read memory\n";


 }

 CloseHandle(handle_prgmA);


}
```

OpenProcess keeps returning error code 87("invalid parameters") and I have no idea why!

Comment: If all you're doing is reading process memory, then you shouldn't open the process for all access - only open the process for the access rights you need (in this case, PROCESS_READ_MEMORY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenProcess` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when you give it a PID of zero. Check to ensure the `operator>>(std::istream&, int&)` call succeeded before calling OpenProcess.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, that was the problem. It turns out from previous std::cin I used << std::hex and it was apparently still used when I was doing input for the PID. Thank you for opening my eyes!